# OSM to OGR - Stream or File - install missing driver

Tags: python, gdal, openstreetmap, ogr, windows-10

I'm trying to convert a .osm-file or overpass stream (both XML-based) into OGR conform layers. I already found an approach which should work:

https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-a-list-of-the-street-names-in-a-osm-file

But `ogr.Open` returns an Nonetype element. Is there any way, I can install the OSM driver into my OGR/GDAL setting?

My configuration:

- Windows 10 x64 - Python 2.7 32bit (because of Arcgis 10.4)
- GDAL Version 2.1.0
- OGR Version 2.0.12

Answer (score 2):

My initial installation of GDAL 2.10 (through anaconda 2) came without an OSM-file driver.

Solution: Downgrade to GDAL 1.11.1